# I want to do Image upload test(feature spec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I want to test Image uploader.

My error is

```
Failure/Error: attach_file "picture", "#{Rails.root}/spec/files/attachment.jpg"

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible file field "picture" that is not disabled
```

My code is
(features/posts_spec.rb)

```
scenario "Access posting screen and post" do
　　 sign_in user
    visit new_post_path
    expect(page).to have_current_path(new_post_path)
    fill_in "share impression", with: "hogehoge"
    attach_file "picture", "#{Rails.root}/spec/files/attachment.jpg"
    click_on "post"
    expect(page).to have_current_path(posts_path)
  end
```

(posts/new.html.erb)

```
 <%= form_with(model: post, local: true) do |f| %>
   <div class="mb-3">
    <%= f.label :picture %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

Update: (posts/new.html)

```
 <form action="/posts" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" ... />
   <div class="mb-3">
     <label for="post_picture">Picture</label>
     <input type="file" name="post[picture]" id="post_picture" />
   </div>
 </form>
```

I was able to match on the name of `post[picture]` (see answer below) but equally the other suggestions of text of "Picture" and id of `post_picture` worked.

Comment: Show the actual HTML the erb template produces instead of the erb template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attach_file` locates the file input element by it's id, name, or associated label text, so `picture` obviously doesn't match any of those.  Without the actual HTML produced by your `erb` template it's impossible to tell exactly what the attributes for your input are, but taking a guess based on your route names you probably want something like one of the following

```
attach_file 'post_picture', "#{Rails.root}/spec/files/attachment.jpg" # match id of the file input
attach_file "post[picture]", "#{Rails.root}/spec/files/attachment.jpg" # match name of the file input
attach_file "Picture", "#{Rails.root}/spec/files/attachment.jpg" # match associated label text
```

The other potential issue you may be dealing with is CSS styling of your file input. If your file input is actually styled to be non-visible and then replaced with some sort of button or image, to make it look nicer, then you will want to use the `make_visible` option which can be passed to `attach_file`. That will temporarily adjust the CSS to make the input visible - attach the file - and then reset the CSS to original state. Something like

```
attach_file 'post_picture', "#{Rails.root}/spec/files/attachment.jpg", make_visible: true
```

Comment: I change `attach_file "post[picture]", "#{Rails.root}/spec/files/attachment.jpg"`and was able to solve the problem. Thank you so much!